# Handle combobox dropdown when combobox moves

Tags: wpf, combobox, scrollviewer

Our WPF application have a ScrollViewer that contains various controls. When a combobox withing this ScrollViewer is opened, and then the user uses the mouse wheel to scroll the ScrollViewer, the combobox control moves, but the dropdown list remains at the same position, which looks awkward.

Is there an easy way to make the combobox close, or the dropdown list's position to update when the ScrollViewer scrolls and change the combobox position?

I know I can handle mouse wheel events, but I have many such situations with a combobox contained within a ScrollViewer, and would love to hear about a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled it by adding the following code in App.xaml.cs:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(ComboBox), UIElement.GotFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(SetSelectedComboBox));
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(ScrollViewer), UIElement.MouseWheelEvent, new MouseWheelEventHandler(OnMouseWheelEvent));

private static WeakReference<ComboBox> _selectedComboBox;

private static void SetSelectedComboBox(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _selectedComboBox = new WeakReference<ComboBox>(sender as ComboBox);
}

// Close dropdown when scrolling with the mouse wheel - QM001866525
private static void OnMouseWheelEvent(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if (_selectedComboBox == null || Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DONT_CLOSE_COMBO_ON_MOUSE_WHEEL") == "1")
    {
        return;
    }

    ComboBox combo;
    if (_selectedComboBox.TryGetTarget(out combo) && combo.IsDropDownOpen)
    {
        combo.IsDropDownOpen = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could handle the `ScrollChanged` Event of the `ScollViewer` and force the `ComboBox` to close the DropDown menu :
Xaml

```
 <ScrollViewer  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_OnScrollChanged">
       <Grid Height="700">
            <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Elt One"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Elt Two"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Elt Three"/>
            </ComboBox>
        </Grid>
   </ScrollViewer>
```

and in the code behind :

```
 private void ScrollViewer_OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. As I wrote, I know I can do this, but I wanted a more generic solution as we have many cmoboboxes and many scrollviewer in our app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the **ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged** event and close the drop-down in a callback, notice that in case you have many items in the comboBox like me, every time the child's **ComboBox.ScrollChanged** event is called, the parent's **ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged** event is called as well. In that case, you can't scroll between the ComboBox items without closing it from the parent's callback - You need to handle it in more complex condition.

Eventually I managed to allow the comboBox scrolling event without closing it by register also to the inner ComboBox's ScrollViewer event:

In XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" CanContentScroll="True" ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged">    
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSource}" Focusable="True" ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="ComboBox_ScrollChanged"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

In code behind:

```
private void ComboBox_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox.IsDropDownOpen && comboBox.IsMouseCaptureWithin && !comboBox.IsFocused)
        {
            comboBox.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox.IsDropDownOpen && !comboBox.IsFocused && comboBox.IsMouseDirectlyOver)
        {
            comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = false;
        }
    }
```